# How should I store time series in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I need to create a database of time series, and perform the following tasks:

create new time series,
update existing time series
query one or several time series at once (for instance all time series for the same date etc...)
Is MongoDB adapted to that and if yes, how should I structure the database? (one time series = one document? Or one document = one entry of the time series, and all these documents form the collection which is the entire time series?)

Any link to tutorial that specifically explain how to manage time series in MongoDB is very much welcome.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The usual answer for any MongoDB schema question is, it depends. But in most cases, for time series schema you'll want to aggregate some of the input into a single document. This article explains what I mean.

http://blog.mongodb.org/post/65517193370/schema-design-for-time-series-data-in-mongodb

There are also some great resources at the bottom of that article too.

Scott